# python pandas filter out rows does not work

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I want to filter a pandas dataframe by one column called `'mid'`, only retain those rows that has the field `'mid'` within a particular range.

My code is as follow:

`df_org` is a dataframe of the structure `['uid','mid','cv1','cv2','cv3']`, and `series_moviesID` is a pandas series that contain all the values I want to use to filter the `df_org` dataframe.

```
filterOut(self, df_org, series_movieID, colName='mid'):
    mask=((df_org[colName]).isin(series_movieID))
    df_filterOut = df_org[mask]
    assert set(df_filterOut['mid']).issubset(set(series_movieID))
    return df_filterOut.reset_index().drop(labels='index', axis=1)
```

But the assert expression could not pass, anyone know the potential mistake?

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave some sample data (e.g. 5 rows), together with the expected result. [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Hm. Your code works for me. Also tried with dupes in s, df, and both and it ran. Any more details you can share?

```
In [2]: s = pd.Series(range(4), index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])

In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(10), 'b': range(10, 20)}, index=range(20, 30))

In [4]:

In [4]: print s
a    0
b    1
c    2
d    3
dtype: int64

In [5]: print df
    a   b
20  0  10
21  1  11
22  2  12
23  3  13
24  4  14
25  5  15
26  6  16
27  7  17
28  8  18
29  9  19

In [6]: def filterOut(df_org, series_movieID, colName='mid'):
   ...:         mask=((df_org[colName]).isin(series_movieID))
   ...:         df_filterOut = df_org[mask]
   ...:         assert set(df_filterOut[colName]).issubset(set(series_movieID))
   ...:         return df_filterOut.reset_index().drop(labels='index', axis=1)
   ...:

In [7]: filterOut(df, s, colName='a')
Out[7]:
   a   b
0  0  10
1  1  11
2  2  12
3  3  13
```